# A problem in Camunda Docs Executable Process Add the ChargeCardWorker.class

Tags: java, camunda

This error occurs when I run the code ChargeCardWorker.class

```
org.camunda.bpm.client.impl.EngineClientException: TASK/CLIENT-02001 Request 'POST http://localhost:8080/engine-rest/external-task/fetchAndLock HTTP/1.1' returned error: status code '404' - message: status code: 404, reason phrase: <!doctype html><html lang='zh'><title>HTTP Status 404</title><h3>Apache Tomcat/8.5.50</h3></html>
    at org.camunda.bpm.client.impl.EngineClientLogger.exceptionWhileReceivingResponse(EngineClientLogger.java:30)
    at org.camunda.bpm.client.impl.RequestExecutor.executeRequest(RequestExecutor.java:97)
    at org.camunda.bpm.client.impl.RequestExecutor.postRequest(RequestExecutor.java:74)
    at org.camunda.bpm.client.impl.EngineClient.fetchAndLock(EngineClient.java:78)
    at org.camunda.bpm.client.topic.impl.TopicSubscriptionManager.fetchAndLock(TopicSubscriptionManager.java:135)
    at org.camunda.bpm.client.topic.impl.TopicSubscriptionManager.acquire(TopicSubscriptionManager.java:101)
    at org.camunda.bpm.client.topic.impl.TopicSubscriptionManager.run(TopicSubscriptionManager.java:87)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.http.client.HttpResponseException: status code: 404, reason phrase: <!doctype html><html lang='zh'>HTTP Status 404<h3>Apache Tomcat/8.5.50</h3></body></html>
    at org.camunda.bpm.client.impl.RequestExecutor$1.handleResponse(RequestExecutor.java:146)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:223)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:165)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:140)
    at org.camunda.bpm.client.impl.RequestExecutor.executeRequest(RequestExecutor.java:88)
    ... 6 more
```

I don't think I made a mistake by following the tutorial.How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 404 error indicates that the API cannot be reached under the URL the client is using.

Check if the *baseUrl* defined in your worker (~line 12) is matches the url under which the server is exposing the REST-API e.g.
`baseUrl("http://localhost:8080/engine-rest")`

Is the port correct? Is the REST API deployed?
Validate this in your browser e.g. by accessing
http://localhost:8080/engine-rest/process-definition/

Possible causes on the server-side:

- the server is not started
- Camunda is not deployed
- the deployment failed (check server log)
- the REST-API (spring boot starter) was not included in the deployment

Depending on which Camunda version and deployment model you are using the rest-api may be accessible under a different URL.

Older:

> ```
> spring-boot -> /rest
> non-spring-boot -> /engine-rest
> ```

From 7.13 onward:

> ```
> only /engine-rest
> ```

Also try http://localhost:8080/engine/process-definition/

Comment: Wasn't the old spring-boot path "rest" not "engine"?